# Problems adding `sample sizes` to ggplot violinplot legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, violin-plot

I have the following ggplot2 violinplot

```
library(ggplot2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + 
             geom_violin() +
             geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, binwidth = 0.01)
```

[image]

It's unclear to me based on previous examples how to put labels in the legend (as seen with `vplot()`. I would like to put an integer just to the right of each label in the legend

```
ctrl 10
trt1 10
trt2 10
```

I've manually calculated these simply with

```
> table(PlantGrowth$group)
```

What is the standard way to automatically do this? I've tried the function

```
give.sample.size <- function(x) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    return(c(y = mean(x), label = length(x)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 


bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) +
   geom_violin() + 
   geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, binwidth = 0.01) + 
   stat_summary(fun.data = give.sample.size, geom = "text")
```

But this wouldn't affect the legend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution is a slight modification of your code. All I did is change the data set by making new labels (`PlantGrowth %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(group2=paste(group,length(group))) %>% 
ungroup()`) and use the new labels as legends (`fill=group2`).

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
bp <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(group2=paste(group,length(group))) %>% 
ungroup(), aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group2)) + geom_violin() +
geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, binwidth = 0.01) + 
stat_summary(fun.data = give.sample.size, geom = "text")
```

Comment: So, `fill` in `aes()` provides a way for users to change the legend? 
I think I'm following the code, but please fill in a few details for me (and others). Thanks for the help! I appreciate it